# Passing arguments interactively to script

Tags: bash, shell, arguments

How can I echo questions to the Terminal, and pass the answers to the same script?

The steps would be:

1. A script that output the questions - one question after the other where I can add the answers after the `:`.

   Example:

   `Number 1: 2`

   `Number 2: 4`

   `Number 3: 6`
2. A way to pass the arguments given in step 1 to the script and calculate the sum.

The final output would be: `12`.

Comment: You might want to look at `expect` for how to pass arguments, or have a script that can take the values in other ways like command line arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you had in mind?

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Number 1: " N1
read -p "Number 2: " N2
read -p "Number 3: " N3
echo "Sum: $((N1 + N2 + N3))"
```